# linux command to kill a process in a running port

Tags: command-line, bash, mac

I have a one-liner alias that I added to my `.bash_profile` to kill process running in 8080

`alias kill8080="kill -9 $(lsof -n -i:8080 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')"`'

when I execute `kill8080`, I get

`-bash: kill: (36404) - No such process`

but when I execute

`lsof -n -i:8080 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'`
89912

then `kill -9 88912`, terminates the process

what is wrong with the one-liner?

btw, This is on Mac OS X

Comment: OSX is off-topic here - however the issue is almost certainly that at least parts of your alias are being evaluated at creation time rather than at run time, due to improper quoting.

Comment: any solution that works?

Comment: This project works on Linux and Mac: https://github.com/jkfran/killport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias cannot work properly as this statement is executed during alias creation and not during run time.

```
lsof -n -i:8080 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'
```

So your alias will only kill this process that opens the port 8080 at the time when you create the alias and not when you are using the alias. The process number created for the alias will be static unless you re-create your alias create a statement each time before running it. So you test this by doing:

```
alias test1="echo $(lsof -n -i:8080 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')"
```

The test1 alias will always echo the same process number even if you manually kill the process and restart another process for port 8080. So the only way to really do this is to a bash script to do this instead of using aliases.

Also, note that the step also will not work if subprocesses are returned for `lsof` in Ubuntu, but I suppose this is not the case in OSX, but just be aware of this. For multiple processes, you will need to use a loop to kill each one but ignoring any error as killing the main process could kill any subprocesses as well.

Edited: You can do this with a one-liner in bash, not as an alias. This will work even if multiple process numbers are returned.

```
for p in `sudo lsof -n -i:8080 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}'`; do sudo kill -9 $p; done
```

PS: You can check all your aliases by entering `alias` at the command prompt. It's a quick way to verify what is actually being created.

Comment: well, in that case, if run `source .bash_profile` from terminal, shouldn't it kill the process running at 8080. It did not

Comment: You aren't executing the kill part of the alias when you create the alias, but the process number is determined during creation. Those are two different things. You need to understand what $() does in alias statement.